Dell XPX 7390 Xubuntu 24.04 Sleep issues
I just got a refurbed XPS 7390 and installed Xubuntu 24.04.
Everything is working fine except it's not resuming from sleep.
When I close the lid and let it sleep, on resume, I have the previous graphical display, but no login box, no keyboard control, etc. Mouse moves around but can't click on anything.
The funny thing is that if I use "systemctl suspend" I can resume from that quite fine - get the password prompt and then can resume my work. Only closing the lid messes everything up.
Edit:
I can see xfce4-screensaver-dialog running but it's not visible. Blindly entering my password restores functionality, so the issue appears to be that the lock screen itself is just not visible.
